# make a bootable usb for windows 8.1 recovery in Ubuntu

Tags: windows-8, live-usb

how do i make a windows 8.1 recovery bootable flash drive in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

The best choice for create a bootable USB in Ubuntu is **multisystem**

This tool allows you to create an USB with multiple bootable OS. (You can add Ubuntu, Debian, Windows XP, Windows 7...

The tutorial on the official page is very well explained on how to do this:

[MultiSystem: Create multiboot usb on linux](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/multiboot-create-a-multiboot-usb-from-linux/)

I will make a resume of the steps you will need to follow:

1. Download multisystem
2. Install multisystem
3. Execute multisystem and choose your USB to use as bootable USB
4. The program will ask you to format the USB in FAT32
5. After the installation a very sample GUI will open and you only need to drag&drop your `.iso` into the window